# The file '/WebResource.axd.aspx' does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

So in my .NET application I'm getting this error once deployed on the server. I don't get it however when testing locally or on another server with the same build.

This isn't a case where I show some code, it's a application wide problem. I've also added:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader"  />
</httpHandlers>
```

The problem isn't necessarily the WebResource.axd file, the issue is that the system is looking for WebResource.axd.**aspx** which of course doesn't exist.

The application still works fine though even with this error I would just really like to resolve it, I'm running v4.0.

Comment: Is the error pointing to a specific place that's expecting the file?

Comment: Right. The error is saying it's location is: /WebResource.axd?d=59S4uZ24bIJfCZB4oMx4AlUCj2fILfXP4_DpZEz98ccD0cO-3gj6nKBLQzRqy8Gh8vVBkAF3R0w-zMo7yv3MD-VEuAs1&t=635328527960000000

Comment: Hmm. Can you paste the contents of that file here?

Comment: (Of the WebResource.axd file)

Comment: O sorry mate. That's not how .NET framework works. These .axd files are virtual and are coming from a system .dll. They're not meant to be edited only configured.

Comment: Oh I thought it contained some XML. Anyway have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project? Also try messing with the permissions on your project directory and make sure everything below it is opened up.

Comment: It looks like an issue with the handler mapping in IIS. Go to IIS Manager -> Your Website -> Handler Mappings and check if *.axd handlers are enabled.